# Scrollbars in Lightning Components

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components

How to get scrollbars in Lightning Components.Standard HTML to get it is not working

```
<div style="width:300px;height:1000px;overflow:scroll;">
```

Comment: Anyone have a answer for this yet?

Comment: Hi @OnttuLindeman You can use newly added Lightning component in the Winter '17, ui:scrollerWrapper that enables native scrolling in Lightning Components Salesforce1 app as well as in Lightning Desktop. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/145964/29317

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use newly added Lightning component in the Winter '17, **ui:scrollerWrapper** that enables native scrolling in Lightning Components Salesforce1 app as well as in Lightning Desktop.

> A `ui:scrollerWrapper` creates a container that enables native
>   scrolling in Salesforce1. This component enables you to nest more than
>   one scroller inside the container. Use the class attribute to define
>   the height and width of the container.

Please find the **code** below:

**Component:-**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <div class="mainWrap">
        <ui:scrollerWrapper class="sWrapTest">
            <ul class="testDiv">        
               <li>In the Winter ’17 release, many of your favorite features 
                   are easier to use than ever before. 
               </li>
               <li>Lightning Experience has a brand new                      
                   navigation bar and lots of critical sales,
                   service, and analytics capabilities. 
               </li>
               <li>You’ve got more options for managing customer and partner
                   communities, running your business from your phone, 
                   and keeping your data and your users secure. 
               </li>
               <li>Not to mention plentiful new
                   customization and app development features, 
                   including custom Lightning apps.
               </li>                      
               <li>Other features require direct action by an administrator 
                   before users can benefit from the new functionality.
               </li>
               <li>If a key feature is also available in Salesforce1, 
                   our mobile app, we mention that in the feature description. 
               </li>
               <li>ui:scrollerWrapper
                   Creates a container that enables native scrolling in 
                   Salesforce1.
               </li>

            </ul>
        </ui:scrollerWrapper>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Style:-**

```
.THIS .sWrapTest {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce has created a "Known Issue" for this problem:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000ePVNAA2

Please click the "This Issue Affects Me" button.

Answer (score 3):

```
class="slds-scrollable--y"
class="slds-scrollable--x"
```

use this class for scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

Standard HTML "overflow:scroll" doesn't work in Lightning components.

You can create a scrollDiv around your div in component and set the following in your css to make it work.

```
 .THIS div.scrollDiv {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: overflow-y is not working for me. Other properties like background-color that I set in scrollDiv class are working fine. Please let me know if could get it to work

Comment: Don't specify height in scrollDiv  class.

Comment: If you don't specify height of parent than browser will automatically add scroller , So far this is the only way.

Comment: I didn't mention height attribute in the CSS class(just width and overflow-y attributes) and I still don't see Horizontal scroll working for me in  Salesforce1.

Comment: Getting errors when i add .THIS div.scrollDiv { width: 100%; overflow-y: auto;
}