# Lightning Component not Scrolling in iphone on Salesforce1 App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, ui, scrolling

I have created a lightning Component which implements "force:appHostable". Now I have added this component into Lightning Component Tab and add it into an App in Lightning Experience.

This tab with lightning components is not working properly in iphone's Salesforce1 App.
I am not able to scroll the list of the data within that page, or scroll the content within it's modal popup, which is on the page as well.

Not found any event like onScroll which let me know about the scrolling in Salesforce1 App on iPhone Device.

Used `slds-scrollable` but didn't work.
Used below CSS, but didn't work.

```
.THIS .mobileScroll{
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Used "ui:scrollerWrapper" as well, but didn't work, which I come to know from below link:-
[Scrollbars in Lightning Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81959/scrollbars-in-lightning-components)

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Try with media queries, and use important key word to -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Comment: Hi @ankitgoel, Can you please post the component code as well? (I would like to have a look on how you've tried wrapping the `ui:scrollerWrapper` and it's corresponding style.) The thing is, scrolling is still not at all smooth even when using `ui:scrollerWrapper`. See [Scroll issue in Salesforce1 | Lightning ui:scrollerWrapper issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173467/scroll-issue-in-salesforce1-lightning-uiscrollerwrapper-issue). Also, slds-scrollable is still not compatible in Salesforce1.